# Change checkbox value without datasource and other than the current one AX2012

Tags: axapta, x++

Is it possible to change the value of a checkbox in the modified method of a form? Since the checkbox I want to change is not the one currently running?

The checkbox has the self-declaration yes and is the same checkbox for the various rows and columns of the form, but when I click on column 11 regardless of the row I want it to be deselected if column 12 is selected.

I've tried this way to make it unselected but it's not working:

```
 table.data(12,line) = FalseTrue::False;
 table.data(12,line).doupdate();
```

or

```
table.data(12,line).set(false);
```

or

```
 table.data(12,line).valueStr(false);
```

I want the checkbox in column number 12 to be unselected if it is selected.